# Line-Line Intersection algorithm generated by the Github Copilot doesn't work in some instances

Tags: kotlin, geometry

```
    // code generated by the GitHub copilot 
    fun lineLineIntersection(line1: LineAbsolute, line2: LineAbsolute) : Vector2?
    {
        val a1 = line1.y2 - line1.y1
        val b1 = line1.x1 - line1.x2
        val c1 = a1 * line1.x1 + b1 * line1.y1
    
        val a2 = line2.y2 - line2.y1
        val b2 = line2.x1 - line2.x2
        val c2 = a2 * line2.x1 + b2 * line2.y1
    
        val determinant = a1 * b2 - a2 * b1
        if (determinant == 0f)
        {
            return null
        }
        else
        {
            val x = (b2 * c1 - b1 * c2) / determinant
            val y = (a1 * c2 - a2 * c1) / determinant
            return Vector2(x, y)
        }
    }
```

and my LineAbsolute class:

```
data class LineAbsolute(var x1: Float, var y1: Float, var x2: Float, var y2: Float)
```

this Input gives the position 3, 1 as a result which is wrong,it must return null

```
        println(lineLineIntersection(
            LineAbsolute(-1f, 0f, 1f, 0.5f),
            LineAbsolute(1f, 1f, 2f, 1f)
        ))
```

It's Illustration:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3h3c.png)

Also

```
println(lineLineIntersection(
            LineAbsolute(0f, 0f, 1f, 0.5f),
            LineAbsolute(1f, 1f, 2f, 1f)
        ))
```

which returns 2, 1 while it should return null

I am unable to fix this code on my own as I don't know anything about it, so I need a bit of help on the line which causes this problem in the function

edit: as @kungphoo pointed out this is actually a ray-ray intersection algorithm, hence why it gives the point where it would intersect if it was of infinite length, so, can someone provide a line-line intersection algorithm pls? every single one that I googled are either too hard to port to kotlin or boolean

Comment: The code looks like a ray-ray intersection algorithm to me.

Comment: oh, so that's why it gives the position where it would intersect, any line-line intersection algorithms u can recommend?